Using variable from another file that needs "import" using a button click
In file 1, I have 2 buttons.
from file2 import Candy

class MyInterface (QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Candy")

        self.candy_instance = Candy(self)
        self.candy_import_button.clicked.connect(self.candy_instance.import_candy)
        self.candy_show_button.clicked.connect(self.candy_instance.show_candy)

In File 2, I have the method to import and show an ODS File
class Candy():
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        self.main_window = main_window

    def import_candy(self):
        path = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open ODS', os.getenv('HOME'), 'ODS(*.ods)')[0]
        all_data = pd.read_excel(path, skiprows=5)
        if all_data.size == 0:
            return
        return all_data

    def show_candy(self):
        self.main_window.tableWidget.setRowCount(all_data.shape[0])
        self.main_window.tableWidget.setColumnCount(all_data.shape[1])
        self.main_window.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(all_data.columns)
    
        for row in all_data.iterrows():
            values = row[1]
            for col_index, value in enumerate(values):
                tableItem = QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                self.main_window.tableWidget.setItem(row[0], col_index, tableItem)

How to pass the variable of all_data from import_candy to show_candy?
The import_candy can only run after the button is clicked.
And after import, I want to show the table with the other button.
I read other questions, and then I tried,
def show_candy(self):
    all_data = import_candy()
    ~

and of course it needs me to import again, so it's not what I want.
after that, I tried to declare Class level variable,
class Candy():
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        self.main_window = main_window
    all_data = None

But I don't know how, If I declared
all_data = Candy.all_data

I have not import anything yet, so isn't it ambiguous?
I just need to pass variable from import_candy to show_candy. Any ideas?

Is it because I didn't use 'self.all_data'? I'm very confused in the last 2 days.

What do you mean by "it needs me to import again"? Does it throw an error?

I doesn't, It can run but not what i want. I already import the file candy_import_button. So i just need candy_show_button to show the file, not import file again.

"Holy hell, i struggled for 2 days. and when asking the question i got the answer. Whyyyy." The power of the Rubber Duck.

Wow! I'll try this Rubber Duck technique more often from now on!

I accidentally got the answer.
What makes it bad is I used all_data instead of self.all_data.
When I globally change all_data  with alt+f2.
The code works fine as i intended.
This is the result.
class Candy():
def __init__(self, main_window):
    self.main_window = main_window
    self.all_data = None #I declared the Variable


def import_candy(self):
    path = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open ODS', os.getenv('HOME'), 'ODS(*.ods)')[0]
    self.all_data = pd.read_excel(path, skiprows=5)
    if self.all_data.size == 0:
        return
    return self.all_data

def show_candy(self):
    self.main_window.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.all_data.shape[0])
    self.main_window.tableWidget.setColumnCount(self.all_data.shape[1])
    self.main_window.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.all_data.columns)

    for row in self.all_data.iterrows():
        values = row[1]
        for col_index, value in enumerate(values):
            tableItem = QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
            self.main_window.tableWidget.setItem(row[0], col_index, tableItem)


This will throw an exception if the second button is clicked before the first, because self.all_data is None. You should at least check if self.all_data is not None, and eventually either return or continue. Note that if import_candy is only run when clicking the button, returning the data is completely useless. Finally, it shouldn't be responsibility of a "child object" to act on its parent, nor to assume its contents or attributes. Right now that Candy class seems completely useless, and you can implement those functions in the main class, avoid unnecessary code complexity.

Right, I'll check if self.all_data is not None. Actually i need more than one File that can handle Candy(), Something like Candy(), Bread(), Milk() and so on. I have many different file to handle, so i want to do it in a different python file. Actually import_candy will not only import a file, this function will also process the file before show_candy can show it into a tablewidget. I just want people to understand my code as easy as possible, so yeah. Thanks.

Files don't handle anything. If you have the possibility of many similar classes, then that's even more important to have a more appropriate object structure, to avoid boilerplate code and reduce the possibility of bugs. That's one of the main reasons for signals and slots: provide proper modularization and separation of concerns, instead of having bits of unrelated or out of context code where it shouldn't be.

What can I do? let's just say i have 3 different ods file generated from a production machine. Each file have different amount of column, some of them are merged cell. I need to show the tablewidget in simpler manner. It's hard to process in just 1 file, no? The ods files are generated from 1 machine so its column are static. It's just each file really have different column and merged cell, So I planned to have 1 python file to handle 1 ods file. or you have simpler solution?

1 python file to handle 1 ods file in a 1 stackedwidget. Let's say I handle Candy in 1 stackedwidget, that stackedwidget is in a form of 1 python file (different file from ui, generated by qt)(I handle the button and navigation bar in a different file too). It's just, 1 pyton file to handle 1 stackedwidget. is it that bad?

Having one or more files is a matter of taste/habits/project structure/code organization/requirements (including development/deployment). It's fine to have many files, yet sometimes it could be better to have just one; other times, having too many files results in excessive fragmentation and difficult code maintenance. Anyway, the point is not the file count (it's often irrelevant for execution), but the logic behind their codes; as said, "files" don't handle anything, they're just one of many ways a program works: in fact, depending on the system and language, a program can perfectly »

» exist without any file at all (for example, a code in a Python interactive shell). We often assume a "program" as a "runnable" file/script, as that's the result of how modern programs generally work, but that's just a simplistic and often misleading interpretation: a program is a set of logic instructions, stored as such (not as "physical files" on the processing memory during execution. For various reasons, nowadays systems don't normally allow deleting a program file while it's running, but that's theoretically doable: in fact, once you start a python script, you can even delete it while »

» it's still running. Multiple code files are for better management (in theory, and if not considering dynamic loading at runtime, eg: "plugins"): from the point of view of the program, it's basically irrelevant. What matters is how its logical elements are semantically organized, and how that structure works in terms of modularity when using OOP. That's why, normally, "child" objects shouldn't assume anything about a "parent" (as you did with self.main_window), and, to some extent, it's also one of the reasons for which using/changing global variables is normally discouraged.

Yes, that's why I want 1 file to handle 1 stackedwidget. Aside from that, normally, "child" objects shouldn't assume anything about a "parent" (as you did with self.main_window) , what do you mean by this? Actually i have 3 files, ui.py , interface.py , and candy.py . without self.main_window , I can't use tablewidget self.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.all_data.shape[0]) from ui.py (ui.py generated from qt designer with pyside-uic)?  then what should I do?

wait, does that mean, I have to declared all_data = None in the file1 MyInterface then change into self.candy_show_button.clicked.connect(self.candy_instance.show_candy(all_data))?

No, that connect() call wouldn't make any sense and will also throw an exception. I strongly suggest you to take your time to do more accurate and patient research about general programming and OOP fundamentals, as it seems clear you are missing a few extremely important aspects. Note that's absolutely nothing wrong with that (everybody starts as a beginner), but approaching more advanced concepts requires proper awareness, and it's important to properly understand some fundamental elements that are often taken as granted (and misunderstood) when learning about programming.

That's why, It doesn't make any sense. Welp, It is what it is. I should learn more about OOP right? I will.
